# Retrieve data from database using asp.net (Incorrect Syntax near 'user')

Tags: c#, asp.net

The error I am receiving is "Incorrect syntax near 'user'" - however, I cannot see anything wrong with my code - does anyone have any ideas?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string db = "";
    db = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnection"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(db);
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM user";
    cmd.Connection = con;
    SqlDataReader dr;
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        Response.Write(dr[0].ToString());
        Response.Write(dr[1].ToString());
        Response.Write(dr[2].ToString());
        Response.Write(dr[3].ToString());
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Do you have a table called user? Is your connection string correct?

Comment: Is it because user is a reserved word (as well as, presumably, the name of your table)? Try `"SELECT * FROM [user]"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
"SELECT * FROM [user]";
```

`user` is a keyword/reserved word. I guess that's the problem. I always end up using `USERS` instead of `user`. Try as much as possible to avoid using reserved words as column names, table names, etc. Use them whenever you can't avoid it

Answer (score 3):

user is a reserved word - you would need to change it to

```
"select * from [user]"
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it because user is a reserved word (as well as, presumably, the name of your table)?

Try

`"SELECT * FROM [user]"`